# Show subset $w$ of a vector space $V$ is a subspace of $V$ if and only if $span(w)=w$.

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces

> Show that if $w$ is a subset of a vector space $V$, $w$ is a subspace of $V$ if and only if $\operatorname{span}(w) = w$.

$\Rightarrow$ We need to prove that $span(w)$$\subseteq$ $w$ and $w$ $\subseteq$ $span(w)$.

For $span(w)$$\subseteq$  $w$, given y $\in$ $span(w)$, by definition of span, y can be written as a linear combination of $u_1x_1+u_2x_2+\cdots+u_nx_n$ $\in$ W for $u_i \in F$ and $x_i \in W$.

For $w$ $\subseteq$ $span(w)$, since $w$ is a subspace. Let $z \in w$. By definition of subspace, it can be written as a linear combination of z=$u_1x_1+u_2x_2+\cdots+u_nx_n$ $\in$ W for $u_i \in F$ and $x_i \in W$.

Is my forward proof ok?

Comment: $w$ is always a subset of $\operatorname{span}(w)$ regardless of whether $w$ is a subspace, so the only interesting part is $\operatorname{span}(w) \subseteq w$. For that part, you haven't stated why $y \in W$.

Comment: I agree with @Bungo  it's not clear why $ span (w) \subset w $

Comment: @Bungo so based on what I have, should I check the properties of subspace to argue that $y \in W$?

Comment: @Beacon Yes, you could say something like "$y$ is a linear combination of elements of $w$, and $w$ is a subspace, so it is is closed under linear combinations, therefore $y \in w$."

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The part of $ w \subset span (w) $ is not very clear to me. It might be better to use the fact that $span (w) = \displaystyle \bigcap_ {U \in \Lambda} U$, where $ \Lambda = \{U \ \mbox{subspace of} \ V: w \subset U \}$

Comment: All this is valid if we have a finite dimentional Vector space right? What if we have an infinite dimentional vspace? How will the proof be then?

Comment: The $w \subset span(w)$ part is the same for the infinite-dimensional space because it does not use finite bases for the proof

Comment: oh yeah!! as span(w) is the minimal subspace which is the intersection of all subspaces which contains w, we didn't say anything about it being finite dimentional or not....Thanks!!!

Answer (score 1):

If $w$ is a subspace, then $w$ is closed under addition and scalar multiplication.  Hence $\operatorname{span}w\subset w$.

Comment: can I also argue that since span by definition, is a intersection of subspaces, it is closed under addition and multiplication. so $span       w \in w$?

Comment: You want $\operatorname{span}w\color{blue}{\subset}w$.  But sure.  The span is the intersection of all the subspaces containing the set.